# Commerce Cloud - How to Embed an Iframe Widget (JS script)

Tags: commerce-cloud

We have self-contained embeddable widget (via a simple `<script>` javascript tag) that can be placed on any regular HTML page.

We'd like to embed this widget into Commerce Cloud, and it seems possible - I looked through the [this trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/cc-digital-for-developers/digital-ref-architecture) on the Commerce Cloud SFRA Architecture and there's mention of "cartridges" being used to implement such a thing:

> The SFRA makes it easy to segment B2C Commerce delivered code, merchant customizations, and third-party integration code into discrete cartridges—making it easier to maintain and update the contents of each cartridge.
>
> In B2C Commerce, a cartridge contains code or data. This means that developers can build new components, for example, features such as wishlist, Apple Pay, and payment integrations, and independently plug them into the storefront.

How would we go about implementing this?  Where do we start?

The full [Commerce Cloud Documentation](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/index.jsp) is involved, and the best I could find that might fit the bill is something called [Pipeline Scripting](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.demandware.dochelp%2FScriptProgramming%2FPipelineScriptingQuickStartExample.html&cp=0_5_14_0), but hesitant to go down this route only to find out there's a better, simpler, more "best practice" way to do this in Commerce Cloud

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have already found the answer to your question already, but in any case, what you need to do is override the `.isml` template of the page you want to embed the iframe into.

You can do this by creating a new template with the same name and under the same folder path, but in a different cartridge.

Then you put this new cartridge in the beginning (left-side) of the cartridge path.

Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Still working on getting a login, but this is really helpful, thank you!